# Find unlisted web pages on a site?

Tags: websites

If I have a website with an `index.html` page that was just a landing page with no other links, and I also have another html page hosted on the same domain that has no links to it, is there any way someone could find the page except through being told that it exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tactics basically amount to guessing:

- **Standard directory testing**: This guesses typical webpage files, like `/manager/login.jsp` and the like.
- **Dictionary Attacks**": This guesses dictionary words, like "employee".

There are many tools that do this, like Burp Suite and Dirbuster.

The other technique that I like to use for finding hidden pages is searching Google. Simply putting in `site:*.example.com` will return every single page on example.com that Google knows about. So, if Google-Bot has stumbled upon your page, I'll know about it too!

There's also the chance that someone will just guess it. It's not that hard. Now, a page like `example.com/lsjglkjlktjwlkfjsldkjfijflkwjflksdjflkdsjflkdsjf` would be quite hard to find :)

Takeaway: if you don't want someone to see it, put an authentication challenge on it.

Answer (score 1):

Along with guessing techniques, another approach is to look at supporting files such as CSS, JS, etc. They may reference additional pages.

Also, look for web server configurations that expose this information such as enabled directory listing.